# How to make code more efficient (create a loop or function) for str.get() from column using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame with the nested fields. I need to extract only the display_value from the columns:
[image]

How to make my code efficient?

```
df['author'] = df['author'].str.get('display_value')
df['assigned'] = df['assigned'].str.get('display_value')
df['closed'] = df['closed'].str.get('display_value')
df['service'] = df['service'].str.get('display_value')
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is cleaner and more efficient:

```py
for column in df.columns:
    df[column] = df[column].str.get('display_value')
```

Comment: great! thanks! how should I create a loop when I have additional columns like: [problem: 
,low
,high
,medium
,high] without the 'display_name' part?